# Converting GeoDataFrame to NetworkX graph with Momepy returns error

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I'm using `OSMnx` to generate a GeoDataFrame that represents the structure of a place (Berlin in my example). To do so, I call the function `geometries_from_place` from `OSMnx` to generate it. I would then like to use the library `momepy` that has the function `gdf_to_nx` that is suppposed to convert a GeoDataFrame (`GeoPandas`) to a graph (`NetworkX`).

```
import momepy
import osmnx as ox

location = 'Berlin'
landmarks = ox.geometries.geometries_from_place(location, tags={'tourism':'attraction'}, buffer_dist=1500)

landmarks_graph = momepy.gdf_to_nx(namedAttractionsDf)
```

Unfortunately I get back the following error from the last line of code:
`NotImplementedError: Component rings have coordinate sequences, but the polygon does not`

My final objective is to apply the `OSMnx` function `ego_graph` to generate the neighborhood of each node of the generated graph, but to do so I have to have a graph.

*I know that I can use the `OSMnx` function `graph_from_place` to generate the graph, but calling both functions (`graph_from_place` and `geometries_from_place`) is too heavy, and technically they carry the same information but differently represented. So, calling both of them would be a repetition of the same request.*

How should I proceed to avoid the error I get?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue, which was caused by my dataframe storing the geometries as `Polygons`, instead of `LineStrings`. I solved it by extracting the boundaries of my polygons, which can be achieved as follows:

```
your_gdf.geometry = your_gdf.geometry.boundaries
```

You may then encounter that your `Polygons` (which in some instances may be `MultiPolygons`) convert to `MultiLineStrings`, to convert the entire dataframe to `LineStrings`, pass `your_gdf.explode()` to `momepy.gdf_to_nx()`, as follows

```
G = momepy.gdf_to_nx(your_gdf.explode())
```